# Html.BeginForm in WebApi - routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a Web API project as part of my solution (also containing an MVC4 project) and within the Api project I am trying to post a form to the Values controller Post method (from a view also within the Api project).

Using `Html.BeginForm()` or `Html.BeginForm("Post", "Values")` posts to `/Values/Post` but I need it to go to `/api/Values/Post`

Any idea which overload or settings I need to post to the correct location?

I can hit all the action methods fine from fiddler (e.g. localhost/api/values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API controller uses a different route to the default. It's supposed to be consumed from JS (AJAX) rather than a real form post so there's no obvious support for it in HtmlHelpers. Try:

```
Html.BeginForm("values", "api")
```

This would trick it into thinking "values" is the action and "api" is the controller. "Post" is inferred from the http method.

Comment: Thanks flem that works :) I may re write the form in Ajax if that's how it should be done

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use `BeginRouteForm` as link generation to Web API routes always depends on the route name. Also make sure to supply the route value called `httproute` as below.

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("DefaultApi", new { controller="Values", httproute="true" }))
```